# angularjs ng-click. Получить текст элемента вызвавшего событие

Tags: angularjs, javascript-events

привет есть событие

```
$scope.selectedByGenre = function($event) {
        $scope.response = httpQuery.getMovieByGenre("name");
        alert(event.target.innerHTML.length);
    }
```

проблема в том что он возвращает длину но не верную при длине
в 4 символа он пишет что длина 44 символа. И  так понимаю он добавляет пробелы.

получаемое имя я передаю в

```
$scope.response = httpQuery.getMovieByGenre("name");
```

вот HTML

```
  <ul class="ul-item">
    <li ng-repeat="genre in genres" ng-click="selectedByGenre($event);">
      {{ genre }}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

UPD
Можно избавится от этого

```
var t = $.trim(event.target.innerHTML);
```

но надо причину узнать почему добавляет пробелы

Все довольно странно
проблема в самой разметки

```
<ul class="ul-item">
        <li ng-repeat="genre in genres" ng-click="selectedByGenre($event);">
          {{ genre }}
        </li>
      </ul>
```

почему то учитываются пробелы между `<li> и </li>`

сделал

```
<li ng-repeat="genre in genres" ng-click="selectedByGenre($event);">{{ genre }</li>
```

и все ок

Comment: Подождите подождите. Зачем вам вообще `event.target.innerHTML`? Это содержимое `li`. В `li` записывается значение `genre`. Значит вам нужен `genre`.

Comment: что бы  в заголовок вставить и по содержимому в li сделать выборку из БД метод  `ng-click="selectedByGenre($event);"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется, вам нужно что-то вроде этого.

Пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/or418wzd/)

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function() {
     var vm = this;
     vm.genres = ["hip-hop","rock", "dance"];
     vm.selectedByGenre = selectedByGenre;
     
     function selectedByGenre(genre){
       console.log(genre);
     }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController as vm">
   <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="genre in vm.genres" ng-click="vm.selectedByGenre(genre);">
      {{genre}}
    </li>   
   </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. да методы у меня уже есть просто проблема была с лишними пробелами